# localize or customize google form checklist in different language

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Checklist has the "Other" option, I would like to change the word other, either for localization, either to write something else.
Is this even possible creating a customized checklist? Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we can't do that.

If this helps you, then Google Form presents for each browser location its version of this word.